# How can I open other people's Outlook calendars from Perl?

Tags: perl, outlook, calendar, shared

I can access my calendar entries as:

```
$folder = $namespace->Folders("Joe Cool")->Folders("Calendar");
```

How do I open "Jane Cool" Calendar? Outlook shows that calendar as:

```
People's Calendar
   Jane Cool
```

Comment: You really need to provide more information. You don't tell us anything about how you access Outlook in the first place.

Comment: Same here: I would like to do the same in my house and normally StackOverflow topics are very helpful. This one isn't. How did you initialize $namespace? Which libraries do/did you use?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220116(office.11).aspx)() method.

Comment: hm, you point to some VB documentation .. as Leon before me, I'd appreciate some more context .. accessing my Outlook from Perl look intriguing ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the whole $namespace datastructure?

Try:

use Data::Dumper;print Dumper $namespace;exit;

somewhere shortly after $namespace gets created/initialised.

Iain